# How to sort a list in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sorting, dart

I am building a list in flutter and need to sort it by date by showing the most recent timestamp first.

The list is created from a json like the one below:

```
[
   {
      "id":100,
      "timestamp":"2021-02-02T15:15:11Z",
      "name":"Entry1"
   },
   {
      "id":101,
      "timestamp":"2021-03-02T11:12:56Z",
      "name":"Entry2"
   }
]
```

Once the json is fetched with the `fetchEntries` function, I'd like to sort the list. This is my code:

```
class Values extends Object {
  int id;
  String timestamp;
  String name;

  Values(
      {this.id,
      this.timestamp,
      this.name});

  Values.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"];
    timestamp = json["timestamp"];
    name = json["name"];
  }
}
List<Values> _myList = [];
    fetchReport() {
        _timer = new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
            fetchEntries(dates.id.toString(), dates.from, dates.to)
                .then((value) => {
                      _myList.addAll(value),
                      _postsController.add(1),
                      setState(() {})
                    });
            _timer.cancel();
        });
        //This is the sort code that doesn't work
        _myList.sort((a,b)=> a.timestamp.compareTo(b.timestamp));
      }
```

Alternatively, the list can be sorted by id in decreasing order but the timestamp method is preferred. Any suggestions how to do it properly?

Comment: You need to parse the timestamps before comparing them.

Comment: And why is timestamp a String?  It should be a DateTime upon ingest, otherwise all users of Values will be independently needing to do the same calculation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to parse time after fetch data.

```
_myList.sort((a,b) {
    
    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
        DateTime aTime = formatter.parse(a["timestamp"]);
        DateTime bTime = formatter.parse(b["timestamp"]);
    
    return aTime.compareTo(bTime);
    //return bTime.compareTo(aTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that issue why sorting does not work is that **_myList.sort** function is called before _myList is filled with data. The reason of that is that _myList is populated in future (when callback of **fetchEntires(...).then**) is called, while sort function is called right after timer is created (after Timer.periodic constructor).

In order to fix that you need to move **_myList.sort** to callback just after list is populated with data.

Regarding sorting itself.. While it should work comparing date in the format of your example, I would rather parse time to milliseconds and then compare those instead. Reason is that once you change date format to different one, like 'dd-MM-yyyy' sorting will be broken.

Comment: Thank you Alex for the hint, it turned out my sort function didn't parse the time string and I was doing the sort before being populated with data! Upvoted!